# AS3 vertical gradient incorrect when large

Tags: actionscript-3, gradient

This seems to be a very straight forward thing to do and there are loads of tutorials about the subject. None of them are helping me get this right though, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

I'm trying to create a simple Flash AS3 GUI component that has a vertical gradient. I create the sprite, and draw the gradient with beginGradientFill and a matrix with a 90 degree radian angle on it. If you look at this output, you see that its not creating a black to white vertical gradient.

```
package
{
   import flash.display.GradientType;
   import flash.display.Shape;
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.geom.Matrix;

   public class Main extends Sprite
   {
      public function Main()
      {
          var theWidth : Number = 800;
          var theHeight: Number = 100;

          var shape1:Shape = new Shape();
          var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
          matrix.createGradientBox(theWidth , theHeight, Math.PI*0.5, 0, 0);
          var colors:Array = [ 0xffffff, 0x000000];
          var alphas:Array = [ 1, 1];
          var ratios:Array = [ 0, 255];
          shape1.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xa1b0b6);
          shape1.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,colors, alphas, ratios, matrix);
          shape1.graphics.drawRect( 0.0, 0.0, theWidth , theHeight);
          shape1.graphics.endFill();
          addChild(shape1);
      }
   }
}
```

If I change

```
matrix.createGradientBox(800, 100, Math.PI*0.5, 0, 0);
```

to

```
matrix.createGradientBox(800, 100, Math.PI, 0, 0);
```

it works fine - but horizontally - why is it that applying 90 degrees the fill does not work?

Thanks for your help, I really don't know whats wrong with this

Comment: Your code works fine to me... (Flashdevelop)

Comment: Really? Ive tried both in flash builder and on this online flash compiler: http://www.victordramba.com/?p=31 - but both results are the same. I see a sort of gradient in grey. It's supposed to be black to white. I really don't get it :S

Comment: take a look at this (http://imm.io/4Fug) and tell me if it is what you want. This is YOUR code output to me. The only thing that I changed was the removal of the 2 pixel thick border. I can see exactly the same with or without the border, except that the border obstruct the outermost pixel of each side of the rect.

Comment: Hi Nemo, I have isolated the problem - its to do with the new Flash player 11. I downloaded and installed it for the molehill API, but it is still in its pre-release phase. Without the flash player 11 the gradient is fine - but with it, it gets messed up. My thoughts are that they have made some changes to the matrix class and this has effected what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your help Nemo, I am going to report this to Adobe in the hope they can fix it in the next release. Mat

Comment: "*I am going to report this to Adobe*" - 1+ for that... And please, edit your post to add this piece of info... It will be more visible in cases where people get in the same trouble that you got...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm, this was a Flash player issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be to translate the Matrix in Y by the height of the box, it's silly working in FP9 worked fine for me without doing that, had the incubator build and looked bad, went back to 10.3 bad again.. might be that now the matrix it's rotated by the center or something that now translation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing your code, it seems like you may be describing this issue that Mario Klingemann has a solution to (of course).

http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000689.php

Comment: Thanks nick, but I actually already tried his solution and it doesn't work either. If you go to http://www.victordramba.com/?p=31 There is a handy online flash compiler, if you copy and paste my code you'll see what I mean. Any other ideas would be very helpful because I have no idea what's wrong :(

Comment: Here is what im seeing: http://gamasaur.co.uk/gradient_problem.jpg I am using flash builder 4, I create a new action script project, i paste my question's code into the constructor, hit run, and the above is what i see. It kind of looks like the gradient is larger than its supposed to be. Any ideas? Just a heads up, im using the new molehill flash version - would this be a cause do you think?

Comment: Ok I think its the flash version Ive got - because when i run it on other pc's that have flash version 10 it works. I am using the new incubator build of flash 11 - so presumably that's the issue :S